# Why does specific heat increase with temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

Except for monoatomic molecules, specific heat increases with increase in temperature. Why?

Comment: Have you heard about the Einstein or the [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Would you kindly explain?

Comment: The short answer is: Because more degrees of freedom become available for depositing energy. (Because degrees of freedom with an excitation energy $E \ll T$ are frozen out and cannot be thermally excited).

Comment: I linked the Wikipedia article - I suggest you read that and come back if you have more specific questions about that.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Without a whole lot more work, that short answer could be a real answer